# Menu Slidebar Lateral con HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

el boton que desplega el menu vertical se desplaza la derecha cuando se abre, me gustaría que el 'toggle-btn' quede fijo/estático y no se mueva, ya que cuando se abre se desplaza al medio del menu y me tapa otras partes y queda feo. 
Me ayudan por favor?

```
  <div id="sidebar">
  <div class="toggle-btn">
    <span>&#9776</span>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Logo Fazt" class="logo">
    </li>
    <li>Inicio</li>
    <li>Perfil</li>
    <li>Pedidos</li>
    <li>Ayuda</li>
    <li>Salir</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  
  #sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #151719;
    left: -200px;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  
  #sidebar.active {
    left: 0px;
  }
  
  #sidebar ul li {
    color: rgba(230, 230, 230, .9);
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, .3);
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .logo {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto; 
  }
  
  #sidebar .toggle-btn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 215px;
    top: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  #sidebar .toggle-btn span {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;

  }
```

**simple mente mi problema es no poder fijar el menu, y no puedo lograrlo por mi mismo, si me pudiera ayudar seria genial gracias.**

Answer (score 1):

Asignando ID al botón, en lugar de clase, es muy fácil agregar también una clase `active` para cambiar junto con el menú.

En HTML solo se cambia `class="toggle-btn"` por `id="toggle-btn"`, en CSS se cambian todos los `#sidebar .toggle-btn` por `#toggle-btn` y se agrega `#toggle-btn.active` para cambiar la posición del botón cuando el menú está activo.

```js
// Ejecutar hasta que todo esté cargado
window.onload = function() {
  // Variable para controlar el botón
  let btn = document.getElementById('toggle-btn');

  // Variable para controlar el menú
  let side = document.getElementById('sidebar');

  // Agregar evento "onclick" al botón
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Agregar o quitar clase "active" a botón y menú
    btn.classList.toggle('active');
    side.classList.toggle('active');
  });
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  
  #sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #151719;
    left: -200px;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  
  #sidebar.active {
    left: 0px;
  }
  
  #sidebar ul li {
    color: rgba(230, 230, 230, .9);
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, .3);
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .logo {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto; 
  }
  
#toggle-btn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 215px;
    top: 12px;
    background: #151719;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
  }
  
#toggle-btn span {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
  }
#toggle-btn.active {
    left:15px;
    background:#777;
  }
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="toggle-btn">
    <span>&#9776</span>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Logo Fazt" class="logo">
    </li>
    <li>Inicio</li>
    <li>Perfil</li>
    <li>Pedidos</li>
    <li>Ayuda</li>
    <li>Salir</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```